# Wildcard *.domain.com for NS records

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

I have a linux server, and i want to turn it into a nameserver, with only one task of answering NS queries for some wildcard domains. For example:

```
*.domain.com.   NS  3600    dns1.p09.nsone.net.
*.domain.com.   NS  3600    dns2.p09.nsone.net.
```

Normally we have to declare full name for NS records:

```
abc.domain.com. NS  3600    dns1.p09.nsone.net.
abc.domain.com. NS  3600    dns2.p09.nsone.net.
```

But i still want to use wildcard NS records: `*.domain.com. NS  dns1.p09.nsone.net.`

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard solution for that already, when `dns1.p09.nsone.net.` is the name server that needs to answer the queries for every possible sub domain and DNS record of example.com it **is** the example.com name server and you simply register that as the authoritative name server for your domain and use:

```
example.com. IN NS dns1.p09.nsone.net.
```